# How to fetch data from one table & insert into another using hibernate mapping

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I'm working on online exam project by using **Struts Spring and Hibernate integration** with mysql & Eclipse kepler.
While submitting the values in registration.jsp page, i'm trying to store that values in two different tables (user_details,address) within the same database. I can able to store them in DB, but i can't able to fetch the user_id which is a foreign key for address table. user_id is the primary key in user_details table.Except user_id in address table, all the other fields are filled with the correct values. I'm trying to use that in address table. But i can't do that. I have attached the code that i'm using right now,

**user.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="UserDetails" table="user_details">
        <id name="user_id" type="int" column="user_id" >
            <generator class="identity">

            </generator>
        </id>
        <property name="first_name" type="string">
            <column name="first_name"/>
        </property>
        <property name="last_name" type="string">
            <column name="last_name"/>
        </property>
        <property name="email" type="string">
            <column name="email"/>
        </property>
        <property name="password" type="string">
            <column name="password"/>
        </property>
        <property name="gender" type="string">
            <column name="gender"/>
        </property>
        <property name="dob" type="int">
            <column name="dob"/>
        </property>
        <property name="phone" type="int">
            <column name="phone"/>
        </property>
        <property name="experience" type="float">
            <column name="experience"/>
        </property>

         <set name="addr" table="address"  
                inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade = "save-update">
            <key>
                <column name="user_id" not-null="false"  />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="UserAddress"  />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**useraddress.hbm.xml**

```
<hibernate-mapping> 
    <class name="UserAddress" table="address">
        <id name="address_id" type="int" column="address_id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="addr_line1" type="string">
            <column name="addr_line_1"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addr_line2" type="string">
            <column name="addr_line_2"/>
        </property>
        <property name="addr_line3" type="string">
            <column name="addr_line_3"/>
        </property>
        <property name="city" type="string">
            <column name="city"/>
        </property>
        <property name="zipcode" type="int">
            <column name="zipcode"/>
        </property>
        <property name="state" type="string">
            <column name="state"/>
        </property>
        <property name="country" type="string">
            <column name="country"/>
        </property>

        <many-to-one name="user_detail" class="UserDetails" fetch="select">
        <column name="user_id" not-null="false"></column>
        </many-to-one>      
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**UserDetails.java**

```
public class UserDetails {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        //@OneToMany (mappedBy="user_details", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @OneToMany (cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy="user_detail")
        public int user_id; //primary key
        private String first_name;
        private String last_name;
        private String email;
        private String password;
        private String gender;
        private int dob;
        private int phone;
        private float experience;
        private Set<UserAddress> addr;//set name

    //getters and setters created
```

**UserAddress.java**

```
public class UserAddress {

@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int address_id; //primary key
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=UserDetails.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private UserDetails user_detail;
        private String addr_line1;
        private String addr_line2;
        private String addr_line3;
        private String city;
        private int zipcode;
        private String state;
        private String country;
        //getters and setters created
```

I think i'm missing something in hibernate mapping part, because i can able to store other address table values except user_id. If anyone is interested to work with the complete code

Comment: Do u have any idea about this question ?? @SJuan76

Comment: i need your help Sir..!! @Andrea Ligios

Comment: Are you sure that is ok for your `UserAddress` class to extend `UserDetails`? Because you have an encapsulation there also...I mean you want an association not an encapsulation. This is how I see the things...

Comment: ya its ok. even if i remove that, same things happen @Setila

Comment: Another idea is that when using mySQL auto-increment, it needs to use the "identity" generator and sometimes errors can happen because of not doing that. So I want to ask you: does your tables in the DB have AUTO INCREMENT attribute attached for the both primary keys?

Comment: yes.. both the primary key is having auto-increment functionality @Setila

Comment: Do you have some other idea ?? @Setila

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using to store and associate the address with a person and vice versa?